# Create and submit device driver to Microsoft

Tags: windows, device-driver

I want to create a .inf Windows driver to my product and submit it to Microsoft. Does anybody already did it? Is there a tutorial with all the steps?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you mean is submitting to Microsoft for certifying your driver, in summary, you have to test your driver with the Windows HCK and then submit results.  For details, [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463010.aspx) is a good place to start for the certification process.

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @MarcosBontempo if this answer helps, please mark this as Answered for benefits to others